# How to wrap the text in <ion-segment-button> in Ionic 2

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Trying the wrap the 2words in ion segment button.I am doing something like this:

```
<ion-segment  class="segment">
      <ion-segment-button class = "button"  value="v1" tappable>
         <div text-wrap>Service Gaurantee</div>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button class = "button" value="v2" tappable>
        <div text-wrap>Service Request</div>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button class = "button" value="v3" tappable>
        <div text-wrap>How it works</div>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button class = "button" value="v4" tappable>
        <div text-wrap>Understand services</div>
     </ion-segment-button>
  </ion-segment>
```

Added following css :

```
.segment{
   height: 70px;

  .button{
     height: 50px;
  }
}
```

But getting the view like following - how to reduce vertical spacing? [image]

Comment: You could try reducing the `line-height`

Comment: This would be a good one to put on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Thanks, @MrLister!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The segments do not look great with so much text but I tried to play with what you want and this sass looks pretty god.

```
  ion-segment-button {
    min-height: 70px;
    line-height: 1.5rem !important;

    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Philip Brack!

Comment: you have no idea how much this shit just saved me finding and searching for these properties thank you brother.

Comment: glad I could help